# Largest number of sides and diagonals

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, combinatorial-geometry

I have asked to solve the following: For given an integer number $n\ge3$, find the largest positive number $k_n$ for which: for every convex $n-$polygon (with $n$ sides), we can find $k_n$ segments, each segment is a side or a diagonal of this $n-$polygon, such that for any two segments, they always has a common point.

For example: $n=3$: Triangle $ABC$ we can choose the set $\{AB,BC,CA\}$ that is
$k_3=3$.

$n=4$: Quadrilateral $ABCD$ then we can choose $\{AB,BC,AC,BD\}$ that is $k_4=4$.

I have no idea to solve this? Could anyone help me?

Comment: Does $AB$ and $CD$ have any common point or am I misunderstanding the question? Because from that set, "any" two segments does not have a common point.

Comment: My mistake, thanks

Comment: $AC$ and $BD$ still does not satisfy the condition.

Comment: no AC,BD are diagonals so they must has a common point

Comment: Oh, that was my bad, I did not see the part "side or diagonal", my apologies.

Comment: You are well-come

Comment: @JieFan What do you mean by “they are diagonals and so must have a common point”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArsenBerk provided an algorithm that shows choosing $n$ such segments is possible, but not that choosing more is impossible. Here is a proof of that.

Suppose that for some convex $n$-gon, $n+1$ segments have been chosen meeting the conditions. We will obtain a contradiction.

By pigeonhole principle, there exists a vertex which is the endpoint of at least two chosen segments. Label that vertex $A_0$, and all the others, in clockwise direction, starting and ending with its neighbours, as $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_{n-1}$. Let the first of these which is connected to $A_0$ (here and henceforth, "connected" means "connected by a chosen segment") be $A_r$ and the last one be $A_{n-s}$, with $1\leq r < n-s \leq n-1$. The maximum number of chosen segments with $A_0$ as endpoint is then $(n-s)-(r-1) = n-s-r+1$.

Any chosen segments not having $A_0$ as an endpoint must be of the form $A_iA_j$ with $1\leq i < j \leq n-1$. If $i > r$, then $A_0A_r \cap A_iA_j = \emptyset$ (because they are non-adjacent sides in the convex quadrilateral $A_0A_rA_iA_j$), so we must have $i \leq r$. Similarly, if $j < n-s$, $A_iA_j \cap A_{n-s}A_0 = \emptyset$, therefore $j \geq n-s$.

Let us relabel the points $A_j$, for which $j \geq n-s$ (there are $s$ of those) as $B_1, B_2, \dots, B_s$, keeping the same clockwise-is-ascending order: $A_{n-s}$ is now $B_1$, and so on. A useful visualization could be that we are painting these points blue; if we also imagine $A_1, \dots, A_r$ as red, then we have shown that all chosen segments not attached to $A_0$ must connect a red point with a blue point.

---

**Lemmma:** In the convex polygon $A_1A_2\dots A_rB_1B_2\dots B_s$, with $r,s \geq 1$, the maximum number of chosen segments of the type $A_iB_j$ so that any two have a point in common, is $r+s-1$.

**Proof:** By induction. If $r+s = 2$, there is altogether only one segment, so that is the maximum that can be chosen. Assume the claim is true for every such polygon with $r+s = t-1$ for some $t > 2$. We prove it for $r+s = t$.

If $r = 1$, then every chosen segment connects the same red point with one of $s = t-1$ blue points, which makes at most $t-1$ segments. Similarly for the case $s = 1$.

Now suppose $r,s > 1$, and at least $t$ segments have been chosen. Consider the vertices $A_1$ and $B_1$. If both of these are endpoints of more than one chosen segment, then each must be connected to at least one other point. Let $A_1$ be connected to $B_j$ ($j > 1$) and $B_1$ be connected to $A_i$ ($i > 1$). But then $A_1A_iB_1B_j$ is a convex quadrilateral with two non-adjacent sides chosen, a contradiction. So at least one of $A_1$ or $B_1$ is an endpoint of at most one chosen segment. If we remove it, in the resulting (still convex) $t-1$-gon we have lost at most one chosen segment, so at least $t-1$ chosen segments remain, contradicting the inductive hypothesis. Therefore at most $t-1= r+s-1$ segments can be chosen.

---

Going back to the original polygon, it has at most $n-s-r+1$ chosen segments attached to $A_0$, and from the lemma, at most $r+s-1$ segments not attached to $A_0$, or in total at most $n$ chosen segments.

Answer (score 4):

I think $k_n = n$. My reasoning is that we can choose the segments systematically in order to see this result:

First, let's choose a point from the $n$-gon $A_1A_2...A_n$. Without loss of generality, we can assume it is regular and choose $A_1$ by using the symmetry. Then every segment that has an end point $A_1$ is included to our count (because $A_1$ will be the common vertex) so there are $(n-1)$ such segments. Now, for the sides $A_1A_2$ and $A_1A_n$, the diagonal $A_2A_n$ also intersects all of other $(n-1)$ segments. And this the maximum we can get because except that diagonal, we cannot find any other diagonal such that it has common points with $A_1A_2$ and $A_1A_n$ both. Therefore, the answer is $k_n = n$.

Now, if we don't have a regular $n$-gon, this argument still holds because $A_1A_2$ and $A_1A_n$ are two sides of the triangle $A_1A_2A_n$ and all other vertices $A_i$ (with $i \ne 1,2,n$) of $n$-gon cannot be placed such that $\angle A_1A_2A_i > 180^\circ$ or $\angle A_1A_nA_i > 180^\circ$ because $n$-gon is convex (Also notice that even the angle was $180^\circ$, since in this case $A_1A_2 \cap A_1A_i = A_1A_2$ there would have been more than one mutual points). Therefore for all $A_i$, $A_1A_i$ intersects $A_nA_2$. And the same reasoning for $k_n=n$ to be maximum is still valid.

[image]

Comment: Haha nice.  We have the same answer, but you added a diagram

Comment: And the OP specified otherwise and also s/he gave an example for $n=4$ as his/her specification. So I took the intersection point as a common point. I did not see a question in this context before so had no chance to know what does that mean unless OP specifies.

Comment: Then this answer is wrong, for $k_6$ we can get $7$

Comment: "We cannot find any other diagonal such that it has common points with $A_1A_2$ and $A_1A_n$ both". Can we?

Comment: In the $9$-got you’ve drawn, $A_3A_n$ intersects every other line

Comment: It does not intersect $A_1A_2$.

Comment: @ArsenBerk Oh I see. The lack of red there made me forget that it was a line in the set. I’m still not convinced that the angles and side lengths don’t effect the answer. Do you have a proof of that?

Comment: I edited my answer according to your feedbacks @Stella Biderman.

Comment: How we prove that, for other kind of such set, the number of segments can not excced than $n$? All I see is that: you only prove $k_n\ge n$ and showed a case, if you choose $A_1A_i$ for $i=2,\ldots,n$, then we could choose only one more segment.

Comment: It wasn't easy to explain so I started with saying "choose the segments systematically" and I assumed we have a regular $n$-gon. For a regular $n$-gon, there is no problem with choosing a vertex $A_1$ in the beginning right (since whichever vertex we choose is the same as choosing another point by renumbering)? And we can choose only two sides of $n$-gon such that they include $A_1$ as one of their end-points (Otherwise the condition will not be satisfied).

Comment: Then if we choose two sides in this way (here, notice that if the sides are not adjacent, we can't choose non-adjacent sides in the first place) then for other segments (which are all be diagonals), we don't have many options. Because except the diagonals with one end point $A_1$ and a specific diagonal $A_2A_n$,  "we cannot find any other diagonal such that it has common points with $A_1A_2$ and $A_1A_n$ both" (choosing a diagonal not satisfying this condition also breaks the main condition given in the question).

Comment: After your point, I found another segment set with $k_n = n$ but choosing those segments is not as systematic as this one. After choosing a vertex $A_1$, we can choose only one side, say $A_1A_2$, from $n$-gon and we can choose $n-1$ diagonals ($n-2$ of them includes $A_1$ as one end-point and $2$ of them includes $A_2$ as one end-point) because of a similar reason with a slight difference: Except that two diagonal, we cannot find diagonals such that they have common points with both $A_1A_2$ and $A_1A_{n-1}$ this time.